# absolutely integrability implies function approaches zero at positive infinity

Tags: improper-integrals, infinity

Is the following statement true?

$$\text{If function $f$ is absolutely integrable on $[0, \infty)$, this implies } \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f (x) = 0.$$

If yes then how would I prove it?

Note: I am considering the Riemann integrability and the function is $(f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R)$.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: It's false. ${}$

Answer (score 0):

It is not true.  Suppose
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if for some integer $n$, } n\le x \le n + \dfrac 1 {2^n}, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = 2 < \infty, \text{ but }\limsup_{n\to\infty} f(x)=1.
$$

Comment: Michael Hardy, thanks for your response. This statement is basically used in the proof of derivative property of Fourier Transform and I want to prove it. I am using couple of documents for the proof of this property that can be found on links. Document 1: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oc5gzu2umblh2zs/Fourier-Transform.pdf?dl=0)  and document 2: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yysa35fpob9yok9/FourierTransform_2.pdf?dl=0) I have highlighted the said statement which I want to prove. Can you guide me, how would I prove it. Thanks.

Comment: The first document to which you link involves a function that is an indefinite integral of an integrable function. That's a hypothesis that your posting didn't mention. $\qquad$

Comment: If we consider the hypothesis as given in the document in first link then is this statement true? If yes then how would I prove it.

Comment: Suppose $$f(x) = \int_0^x g(u)\,du,$$ i.e. $f$ is the indefinite integral of an integrable function $g$, and $$\int_0^\infty |g(x)|\,dx<\infty,$$ (that's what it means to say $g$ is "integrable") and as above we have $$\int_0^\infty |f(x)|\,dx<\infty.$$ Then question is whether it follows that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$. I may return to this tomorrow. $\qquad$